# Binding data to JQuery Data Table is too slow

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I am working on JQuery Data Table in Asp.Net MVC4. If i am binding data to table, its taking more than 30 sec to load 500 rows. I am not able to identify to find this issue. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

This is my data table code.

```
var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable();
$('#myDataTable').dataTable({
    "bDestroy": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bSearchable": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("GetReportDetails", "DailyReport")',
        "bVisible": true,
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "oLanguage": {
        "sProcessing": '<img src="../../Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/page-loader.gif" />'
    },
        "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
        if (oSettings.bSorted || oSettings.bFiltered) {
            for (var i = 0, iLen = oSettings.aiDisplay.length; i < iLen; i++) {
                $('td:eq(0)', oSettings.aoData[oSettings.aiDisplay[i]].nTr).html(i + 1);
            }
        }
    },
        "aoColumns": [{
        "mData": "DailyReport",
        align: 'left',
        sWidth: '18%',
            "bVisible": false,
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
            return "<div class='scrollcol' width='80%'>" + data + "</div>";
        }
    }, {
        "mData": "Achivement",
        align: 'left',
            "bVisible": false,
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
            return "<div class='scrollcol' style='width:145px'>" + data + "</div>";
        }
    }, {
        "mData": "Comment",
        align: 'left',
        sWidth: '4%',
            "bVisible": false,
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
            if (data != null) return "<div class='scrollcol'>" + data + "</div>";
            else return "<div class='scrollcol'></div>";
        }
    }, {
        "mData": "Rating",
            "bSortable": false,
        align: 'left',
            "bVisible": false
        }
    }, {
        "mData": "CreatedBy",
        align: 'left',
            "bVisible": false
    },

    ],
        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
        $(nRow).on('click', function () {
            var dReportId = aData.DReportId;
            var achive = aData.Achivement;
            var comment = aData.Comment;
            document.getElementById('comment').value = comment;
            document.getElementById('hidNxtIndexId').value = iDisplayIndex;
        });
    }
});
});
```

This is my HTML:

```html
<table id="myDataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Daily Report</th>
            <th>Achievement</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
            <th>Ratings</th>
            <th>Created By</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I would suggest the issue is on the server side. Have you checked in the console to see how long the call to `/DailyReport/GetReportDetails` is taking? You probably need to optimise that.

Comment: I have checked in browser console. Its taking more than 25 sec. when buffering gets stopped then its binding to data table

Comment: There is your problem then. Without seeing that server side code we cannot help you though.

Comment: Yeah its true. I have written complicated linq query.

Comment: LINQ gets slow when you have a lot of logic. I would suggest as a first step to try and use Store Procedures (assuming you're using a SQL implementation as a datastore), and also paging.

Comment: ok i will try to Use stored procedures. Thank you very much for your for your valuable  suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to speed up datatable you can try these three options :-

1. A javascript array will certainly help since you will be able to get the benefit of deferred rendering then. At the moment the browser is creating 500 rows, and then reading them all back from HTML, which is slow. Dumping it into an array and then feeding it to DataTables using the `aaData` or `data`(in newer versions) option.
2. Instead of rendering all data at once, Lazy loading can help you - for eg. you render first 100 items, when page is scrolled to the bottom on the list you render + 100 and so on.
3. If you don't want client side options then you can do some optimization on **server side** also(by optimizing your query which is returning 500 records.).